# C++ for-loop string comparison logic is flawed

Tags: c++, variables, for-loop, logic, string-comparison

My question is: How do I pass the first_In_Line and last_In_Line variables out of the for-loop, so that my final statements receive the variables and display properly?

I'm making an assumption the students do not have the same name.

```
// This program allows a user to define class size, between 1 and 25
// students, and give a list of names. It does not store a list 
// of names, but does sort the names to determine alphabetically, 
// which student will be first in line, and who will be last.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Non-user defined variables
int     num_Students = 0;

string  first_In_Line = "",
        last_In_Line = "",
        previous_Name = "";

bool compare = true;

// User defined variable.
string  next_name;



// Get number of students from user between 1 and 25
cout << "Please enter the number of students in class between 1 and 25: ";
cin >> num_Students;

// Validate user input
while (num_Students < 1 || num_Students > 25)
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 25.";
    cin >> num_Students;
}


for (int i = 1; i <= num_Students; i++)
{
    cout << "What is the name of student " << i << "? ";
    cin >> next_name;

    if (compare == true)
    {
        if (next_name < previous_Name)
        {
        first_In_Line = next_name;
        last_In_Line = previous_Name;
        }

        else if (next_name > previous_Name)
        {
        first_In_Line = previous_Name;
        last_In_Line = next_name;
        }
    }
    // Set compare to "true" to execute if statements next 
    // iteration of for-loop
    compare = true;
    previous_Name = next_name;
}

cout << first_In_Line << " is first in line." << endl;
cout << "And " << last_In_Line << " is last in line." << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Output is this, with the names not properly:

Please enter the number of students in class between 1 and 25: 3
What is the name of student 1? adam
What is the name of student 2? matt
What is the name of student 3? zed
matt is first in line.
And zed is last in line.

Comment: Erm, you mentioned a question... what was it?

Comment: good point... will edit

Comment: Your variables are declared outside of the for loop, they are still there after the loop, you don't have to "pass" them. How are you using your program ? (But yes, your logic is faulty : you never compare new names with your `first_In_Line` and `last_In_Line`.)

Comment: Ok, I'll make that change

Comment: I'm using the program in a class I'm taking for educational purposes.

Comment: Your "question" is obviously not related to your actual problem. Perhaps you could fix that.

Comment: What I meant is how are you running it, because I didn't understand how you could get empty names on output when running your program.

Comment: I've edited the code before you first saw it.

Comment: please do not edit so frequently. The text still has the old question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the use of previous_name and just use the loop to go through your names. All you care about is the first and last person in line.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num_Students; i++)
{
    cout << "What is the name of student " << i << "? ";
    cin >> next_name;
    if (i == 1) // initialize your first entry as first and last in line (min, max)
    {
        first_In_Line = next_name;
        last_In_Line = next_name;
    }
    else // compare for last and first in line (min, max) after first iteration of for loop
    {
        if (next_name > last_In_Line)
            last_In_Line = next_name;
        else if (next_name < first_In_Line)
            first_In_Line = next_name;          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not test if the students have the same name. You should.
You also want to consider the case where the user enter only 1 student.
That being said, your program works just fine when I run it.

Comment: I'm making the assumption the students don't have the same name.

Comment: when 1 student is entered, his name is compared to ""

Comment: it works for some cases but not all. Try adam, eve, zoe. I got eve placed first

Comment: that is what the code does. He should test against first_In_Line instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that you've changed what you said it was outputting-

```
if (next_name < previous_Name)
    {
    first_In_Line = next_name;
    last_In_Line = previous_Name;
    }

    else if (next_name > previous_Name)
    {
    first_In_Line = previous_Name;
    last_In_Line = next_name;
    }
```

You're comparing next_name against previous name, when you should be comparing next_name against first_in_Line and last_In_Line. As it is, your program will always populate first_in_Line and last_In_Line with next_name and previous_Name, even if neither should be first or last.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. Actually they are not related to your question. You do not have to do anything special to "pass the variables out of the loop" as long as they are declared outside the loop (read about [scope of a variable](https://www.google.de/search?q=scope+of+a+variable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=KY4BVu_EE4WiU4OVjIAB)). I was hesitating to write you an answer, because you would learn more if you would fix it yourself. However, here we go:

- You have duplicate code for reading the number of students. You do not need that.
- You do not need the variable `compare`. Anyway you have to compare in each iteration.
- You compare the new name to the last name. Why? To find the maximum/minimum you have to compare to the so far minimum/maximum not to the last value.

Here is the modified code. I didnt test it, just to make sure I didnt do all the work for you :P

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int     num_Students = 0;
    string  first="aaa",last="xxx",name;

    while (num_Students < 1 || num_Students > 25) {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 25.";
        cin >> num_Students;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_Students; i++) {
        cout << "What is the name of student " << i+1 << "? ";
        cin >> name;
        if (name < fist){first_In_Line = name;}
        if (name > last){last_In_Line = name;}
    }
    cout << first << " is first in line." << endl;
    cout << "And " << last << " is last in line." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't work at all. You're never changing first or last, and you've got them backwards in the first place- "aaa" should be last (so that it will always be replaced by the first student entered) and "xxx" should be first, so that it will also always be replaced by the first student. Unless she's named Zoe or Zelda. Or Mr. Aa, since while unlikely, "aaa" is still within the bonds of valid input.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings I mentionted that the code is not tested. You are right: this wont compile, but those are just typos and should be easy to fix